# How to resolve the issue with signed zero?

Tags: fortran

I came to know about 'signed zeroes' only now as I am trying to deal with complex numbers. Here is the problem:

```
PROGRAM sZ
       IMPLICIT NONE
       REAL(KIND(0.d0)),PARAMETER :: r=0.2
       COMPLEX(KIND(0.d0)) :: c0
       c0=(0.0,0.5); print*,sqrt(c0**2-r)
       c0=(-0.0,0.5); print*,sqrt(c0**2-r)
       END PROGRAM sZ
```

The sign of the imaginary part changes.

```
(0.0000000000000000,0.67082039547127081)
(0.0000000000000000,-0.67082039547127081)
```

Any instructions/suggestions to resolve this issue are very much welcome.

Comment: Why is this an issue? They're both valid square roots of `(0.0,0.5)`. Without knowing why this is a problem it's hard to suggest solutions.

Comment: This question has been asked elsewhere and answered.  It should be closed.

Comment: Sorry for crossposting. However, a few more points and suggestions came out that and I would like to share it, in case someone is interested. https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/issue-with-signed-zero/2585

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you see follow from the intermediate step and the specification of the `sqrt` intrinsic.

The final result depends on the value of the argument to `sqrt`: as the result has real part the sign of the result's imaginary part [is that of the sign of the argument's imaginary part](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53086414/3157076).

What are the signs of the imaginary parts of the two arguments?  The imaginary parts of `(0.,0.5)` and `(-0.,0.5)` squared are positive in the first case and negative in the second (with the expected implementation of signed zero). Subtracting a real entity does not affect the sign of the imaginary part of the object which becomes the argument to `sqrt`.

---

At one level, you are getting the correct result so the only thing to resolve is your expectation of getting the same result. However, consider

```
  implicit none

  complex :: z1=(-1.,0.), z2=(-1.,-0.)

  print*, z1==z2, SQRT(z1)==SQRT(z2)
end program
```

It is easy to see why this is confusing even if correct. If we don't want this to happen, we can force any zero imaginary part to be of one particular sign (say, non-negative):

```
! Force imaginary part away from -0.
if (z%Im==0.) z%Im = 0.
```

(A comment for this is very necessary.)

We can access and set the imaginary part of a complex variable using the `z%Im` designator, but this is not possible for general expressions. You may want to create a function for more general use:

```
  implicit none

  complex :: z1=(-1.,0.), z2=(-1.,-0.)

  print*, z1==z2, SQRT(z1)==SQRT(z2)
  print*, z1==z2, SQRT(design_0imag(z1))==SQRT(design_0imag(z2))

contains

  pure complex function design_0imag(z) result(zp)
    complex, intent(in) :: z
    zp = z
    if (zp%Im==0.) zp%Im = 0.
  end function design_0imag

end program
```

As shown by other answers, there are several ways to implement logic replacing `-0` with `0` (leaving other values unchanged). Remember that you experience this only when the result is purely imaginary.

Comment: Nice. This is very nice. Thank you for the detailed discussion.

Comment: Could an optimising compiler cause problems here? Is there a case for using something like `If(zp%Im==ieee_value( Real( 0.0, Kind( zp%Im ) ), ieee_negative_zero ) zp%Im = 0.0` ? (I may well have got this wrong, never used it, but hopefully the idea is clear)

Comment: @IanBush, that's a good question but not one a comment answer can do justice to. Short answer is: yes, but. Behaviour of my answer, the question, and your comment is not determined by Fortran so any "optimization" is ill-defined. (I'd happily upvote and answer a good question on this topic.)

Comment: @IanBush, part of my function relies on: no optimizing Fortran compiler can say `-0./=0.` and still be a Fortran compiler, regardless of IEEE, or kind.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks. I'm happy that a compiler can't say `-0.0/=0.0`, but I feel far from qualified to give any justice to the the other parts.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this, so a signed (negative) zero is just caught and replaced with zero.

```
PROGRAM sZ
      IMPLICIT NONE

      REAL(KIND(0.d0)),PARAMETER :: r=0.2
      COMPLEX(KIND(0.d0)) :: c0

      REAL(KIND(0.d0)),PARAMETER :: i = -0.0
      REAL(KIND(0.d0)),PARAMETER :: j = 0.5
      REAL(KIND(0.d0)),PARAMETER :: zero = 0.0

      if (i .EQ. 0) then
              c0 = (zero, j); print*,sqrt(c0**2-r)
      else
              c0=(i, j); print*,sqrt(c0**2-r)
      end if

END PROGRAM sZ
```

Comment: Hmmm... That's one possibility but I have got another hack. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have devised one little hack to remove this *signed zeros*.

```
PROGRAM sZ
       IMPLICIT NONE
       REAL(KIND(0.d0)),PARAMETER :: r=0.2
       COMPLEX(KIND(0.d0)) :: c0,zero

       zero=(0.0,0.0)
       c0=(0.0,0.5); c0=c0+zero; print*,sqrt(c0**2-r)
       c0=(-0.0,0.5); c0=c0+zero; print*,sqrt(c0**2-r)

       END PROGRAM sZ
```

Now the results are same. :)

However, I would like to know more on this. When are *signed zeroes* necessary?

Comment: It seems like you have a new question. I am not sure if it is a good fit for Stack Overflow or for a different site (Computer Science ?) but it should certainly be asked in a different post.